# If $(a-b+5)x^2 + (2b+1)y^2 = b^2-2b-11$ is the equation of a unit circle, then find the sum of the possible values of $ab$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 
$$(a-b+5)x^2 + (2b+1)y^2 = b^2-2b-11$$ 
is the equation of the unit circle, then what is the sum of the values ​​that $ab$ can take?

Comment: A unit circle has the radius of $1$

Comment: I know. I equalized coefficient 1 and each other but I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extended hint ...

---

The standard equation for an origin-centered unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$. More generally, such a circle has the equation
$$p x^2 + p y^2 = p$$
for any non-zero $p$. Therefore, for $$(a-b+5)x^2+(2b+1)y^2=b^2-2b-11 \tag{1}$$
to be the equation of a unit circle, the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$, and the expression on the right-hand side, must all be equal (and non-zero).
$$a-b+5=2b+1=b^2-2b-11  \quad(\neq 0)\tag{2}$$
The last two parts of $(2)$ allow us to solve for $b$:
$$2b+1=b^2-2b-11 \quad\to\quad b^2-4b-12=0 \tag{3}$$
The first two parts of $(2)$ then tell us what $a$ is:
$$a-b+5=2b+1 \quad\to\quad a=3b-4 \tag{4}$$

The rest of the exercise is left to the reader.

Comment: I found $b_1= 6,b_2= -2,a_1= 14,a_2= -10$ and multiply the values that I found but I could not reach answer.

Comment: @Hatm00: Those are the values I got, too. :) Put another way, we can say that one solution is $(a,b)=(6,14)$, the other is $(a,b)=(-2,-10)$. That's the hard part, so congratulations on getting that far. Now, you just have to deal with how the question wants those values to be combined into a single numerical answer. So ...  For each solution $(a,b)$, what is the product $ab$? And, then, what is the sum of those two products?

Comment: If I multiply $a_1,b_1$ and $a_2,b_2$ after that add them. I can reach the answer but why we can't multiply $a_1,b_2$ ?

Comment: @Hatm00: I believe the expectation is that you multiply only the $a$s and $b$s that "go together".

Comment: @Hatm00: $ab$ cannot take the value -60 nor -28, because in such "combined" case 
we would  not have a unit circle.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks so much for your help.